# allocate matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, malloc

i want to allocate a matrix.

is this the only option:

```
int** mat = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*))

for (int index=0;index<row;++index)
{
    mat[index] = (int*)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well, you didn't give us a complete implementation. I assume that you meant.

```
int **mat = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) mat[i] = (int *)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
```

Here's another option:

```
int *mat = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

Then, you simulate the matrix using

```
int offset = i * cols + j;
// now mat[offset] corresponds to m(i, j)
```

for row-major ordering and

```
int offset = i + rows * j;
// not mat[offset] corresponds to m(i, j)
```

for column-major ordering.

One of these two options is actually the preferred way of handling a matrix in C. This is because now the matrix will be stored contiguously in memory and you benefit from [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). Basically, the CPU cache will a lot happier with you.

Comment: if your compiler supports variable-length arrays or if `cols` is a compile-time constant, you don't even need to compute the offsets yourself; if you use `int (*mat)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *mat)`, you can access the elements via `mat[i][j]` and still use a contiguous block of memory

Comment: Even ignoring performance, a single allocation is also preferable because it's simpler.  There are fewer things to deallocate later, and there's no need to deal with partial allocation failures.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a problem if each malloc created discontinuous memory blocks, making their addresses not serial? For example, the first malloc could return the pointer 0x635 and the other mallocs could return pointers 0xA279, 0xB7DD, etc.. If this happens a simple calculation such as stated above would not work.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers already covered these, but for completeness, the comp.lang.c FAQ has a relevant entry:

[How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Comment: http://c-faq.com is an extraordinary source of such things like C hacks (for C++ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/)

Answer (score 5):

what you can do is

```
int (*mat)[col];
mat=(int (*)[col])malloc(sizeof(*mat)*row);
```

and then use this new matrix as mat[i][j]

Answer (score 3):

You may also use calloc, which will additionally zero initialize the matrix for you. The signature is slightly different:

```
int *mat = (int *)calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just:

```
int* mat = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** collapse it to one call to malloc, but if you want to use a 2d array style, you still need the for loop.

```
int** matrix = (int*)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int) + rows * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    matrix[i] = matrix + rows * sizeof(int*) + rows * cols * sizeof(int) * i;
}
```

Untested, but you get the idea. Otherwise, I'd stick with what Jason suggests.

Comment: this only works if `sizeof (int) == sizeof (int *)` - otherwise, the offset will be wrong; it actually might be wrong even if this is the case

Comment: @Christoph: Good point, and that's easy to work around too, but like I noted in my answer, this is untested. Fixed this now.