# Allocating memory for a matrix in C, why can't I access the matrix afterwards?

Tags: c, memory-management, matrix, malloc

I'm using `malloc` to allocate memory for a matrix, but afterwards any access I do to the matrix to set an element for example gets me a segmentation fault.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
int **matrix = malloc(rows_number * columns_number * sizeof(int));

if (matrix) matrix[0][0] = 1;
```

Why can't I access the matrix after it was created? The `malloc` call is successful so I have enough contiguous memory for the whole matrix.

Comment: malloc is the least understood, most questioned part of the C language - please search here and elsewhere for a plethora of answers to this and every other imaginable question about this subject.  honestly, I can't believe there is a question about malloc that hasn't been asked -- and answered :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [allocate matrix in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128728/allocate-matrix-in-c)

Comment: See the top answer on this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c>

Comment: @BimmerM3, that top answer is just wrong. This is not a 2D array but a pointer to pointer emulation of a 2D array. C has native support for 2D array, why not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have allocated just memory, yet you have declared your object as a set of pointers to pointers. The double subscript requires a pointer vector pointing to each row *or* a type that tells the compiler how many columns there are.

So some options are:

- do the subscript calculation with code, perhaps using a macro
- do two `mallocs()` and initialize a row pointer vector
- malloc an object of a specific type so the compiler can see it

For example...

```
int (*matrix)[ROWS][COLS] = malloc(ROWS * COLS * sizeof(int));
...
(*matrix)[i][j]
```

The following declaration would also work:

```
int (*matrix)[][COLS] = malloc(ROWS * COLS * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I see what I was doing wrong. I'm marking this answer as the accepted one because it seems to be the most complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`int **matrix` declares `matrix` to be a pointer to a pointer to `int`. You want a pointer to an array of `int`. This would be `int (*matrix)[columns_number]`. You can allocate it nicely with:

```
int (*matrix)[columns_number] = malloc(rows_number * sizeof *matrix);
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer, I marked the other one as the accepted one because it seemed more complete but I like this way of doing it because the access to the matrix is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated memory for a dynamic array of *int pointers*, not *int elements*. You could try something like this:

```
int *matrix_storage = malloc(rows_number * columns_number * sizeof(int));
int **matrix = malloc(rows_number * sizeof(int*));
for( int i = 0; i < rows_number; ++i )
    matrix[i] = &matrix_storage[ i * columns_number ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Malloc returns a void pointer so you haven't made a 2 dimensional array.  Try something like:

```
int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(rows_number * sizeof(int*));
for (int i=0; i<rows_number; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(columns_number * sizeof(int));
```