# Pointer to a 2-D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Please, I am new to C programming, please help me this.There is some error in the following code?
Basically, how do we work with pointers to 2-D arrays...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* max5(int** p,int r,int c)
{

/* have to design a function which takes as argument pointer to a 2-D array and returns a pointer to an array which contains the 5 highest entries*/

}

int main()

{

    int rows,coloumns;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and coloumns separated by a space\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&rows,&coloumns);
    int **ptr;

    ptr=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<coloumns;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",*(ptr+i)+j);
            printf("%d\n",*(*(ptr+i)+j));
        }
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no pointers to 2D arrays here. [And don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: It is a good idea to compile and execute this code. Do you have some specific problem?

Comment: you need `ptr[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*coloumns);`

Comment: You have a malloc for (int**)rows, but no allocation for the columns.  Was this intended?

Answer (score 1):

In C, a 2D array is simply a regular array with different indexing. So, you have two options:

1. Allocate an array and index it as: `array[I*n+j]`
2. Allocate an array of arrays (which is what you seem to be trying to do)

The second you can achieve in the way shown in the related post: [allocate matrix in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128728/allocate-matrix-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically allocating a 2D array can be done in several ways.

Assuming you have a C99 compiler or C2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays, this is dead easy:

```
int rows, columns;
...
scanf("%d %d",&rows,&columns);
int array[rows][columns];
```

`array` is a variable-length array (VLA), meaning its dimensions are established at run time.  To pass this to another function, the prototype would simply be

```
int *max5( int rows, int columns, int arr[rows][columns] ) { ... }
```

which can also be written as

```
int *max5( int rows, int columns, int (*arr)[columns] ) { ... }
```

I'll get into that second form below.  Note that both `rows` and `columns` must be declared before you use them in the VLA declaraion.

You would call it as

```
int *maxarr = max5( rows, columns, array );
```

The advantage of this approach is that a) it's easy, and b) the memory for `array` is allocated contiguously (i.e., as a single, continuous block of memory) and released as soon as you exit it's enclosing scope; there's no need to manually `free` it.  The *disadvantage* of this approach is that `rows` and `columns` can't be arbitrarily large, you can't initialize the array using regular initializer syntax (i.e., you can't write `int array[rows][columns] = { ... };`), and you can't define VLAs at file scope (i.e., as a global variable).  There's also the problem that VLA support has always been a little spotty, and the 2011 standard now makes them optional, so it's not guaranteed they'll be supported everywhere.

If `rows` or `columns` is very large, or if for some other reason you want to allocate this memory from the heap, it's just slightly more complicated:

```
int rows, columns;
...
scanf("%d %d", rows, columns);
int (*array)[columns] = malloc( sizeof *array * rows );
```

In this version, `array` is a *pointer* to an N-element array of `int` (where N == `columns`), and we `malloc` space to hold M such arrays (where M == `rows`).  Again, this takes advantage of VLA syntax, but instead of allocating the memory from the stack frame, we allocate it from the heap.  Like in the first method, the memory is allocated contiguously.  You would index into it as you would any other array:

```
array[i][j] = x;
```

When you're done with the array, you would free it as

```
free( array );
```

The prototype for `max5` would be

```
int *max5( int rows, int columns, int (*arr)[columns] ) { ... }
```

Look familiar?  That's the second version we used earlier when we were passing a 2D VLA.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

In the first case where we declared `array` as a 2D VLA, when you call

```
int *maxarr = max5( rows, columns, array );
```

the expression `array` is converted from type "`rows`-element array of `columns`-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `columns`-element array of `int`", so what `max5` receives is a pointer value, not an array.  It just so happens that in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both interpreted as `T *a`; IOW, all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.

Thus, both

```
int *max5( int rows, int columns, int arr[rows][columns] ) { ... }
```

and

```
int *max5( int rows, int columns, int (*arr)[columns] ) { ... }
```

declare `arr` as a pointer to an array, not a 2D array.  Similarly, both return a simple `int *`, as opposed to an array of `int`.  The reason for this is simple; if you return a subarray using

```
return arr[i];
```

the expression `arr[i]` will have type "`columns`-element array of `int`"; by the rule above, that expression will be converted to type `int *`.  C doesn't allow you to return array objects *as arrays*, nor can an array expression be the target of an assignment.

Now, what if you're working with a C89 compiler, or a C2011 compiler that doesn't support VLAs?  In this case, you'd need to allocate the memory in a piecemeal fashion, like so:

```
int rows, columns;
int **array;
...
scanf("%d %d", rows, columns);
array = malloc( sizeof *array * rows );
if ( array )
{
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
   {
     array[i] = malloc( sizeof *array[i] * columns );
   }
}
```

Your `max5` prototype would now be

```
int *max5( int rows, int columns, int **arr );
```

You're not dealing with arrays or pointers to arrays anymore; you're dealing with a double pointer, which is not the same thing as a pointer to a 2D array.  You can still subscript it *as though* it were a 2D array

```
arr[i][j] = x;
```

but it is *not* an array object in and of itself.

The most important thing to realize is that the memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous; rows may not be adjacent in memory, so you *don't* want to try to walk down rows using a pointer, like so:

```
int (*p)[columns] = arr;
while ( some_condition )
  p++; // sets p to point to the next row
```

For an array that was allocated piecemeal, that sort of algorithm won't work.

Also, since the memory was allocated piecemeal, it needs to be freed piecemeal:

```
for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  free(array[i]);
free( array );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @haccks: It's the day before Christmas and I don't want to work on what I'm supposed to be working on.  Besides, I've written a variation of this answer several times already, so it didn't take too long to write.

Comment: Oh! Thank God for clarifying. You know I was thinking about your patience to write such a long answer.

Answer (score 0):

this code  fix your issue :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* max5(int** p,int r,int c)
{

/* have to design a function which takes as argument pointer to a 2-D array and returns a pointer to an array which contains the 5 highest entries*/

}

int main()

{

    int rows,coloumns;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and coloumns separated by a space\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&rows,&coloumns);
    int **ptr;
    int i,j;

    ptr=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
    for(j=0;j<coloumns;j++)
    {
        *(ptr+j) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*coloumns);
    }

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<coloumns;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",*(ptr+i)+j);
           //*(*(ptr+j)+i) = i+j;
            printf("%d\n",*(*(ptr+i)+j));
        }
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

in fact you forget to allocate memory for columns !

Answer (score -1):

You can allocate a 2D array in C by defining the type correctly:

```
int (*ptr)[coloumns] = calloc(sizeof(int) , rows * coloumns);
```

Then you can address it via `ptr[i][j]`. If your array does need to persist beyond the scope that allocated it and is fairly small then you can also allocate it on the stack

```
int ptr[rows][coloumns];
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
```

What you are trying to allocate is an array of pointers `int (*)[coloumns]` is not the same type as `int **` although they can be both addressed through the use of the indexing operator `[i][j]`. The latter is a far more complicated data structure and is prone to more errors. I would advise against it unless you need variable row sizes.