# Allocate a matrix in C using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, double, malloc

I wrote a C code that usea a matrix of double:

```
double y[LENGTH][4];
```

whith `LENGTH=200000` I have no problem.

I have to increase the numbers of *rows* to `LENGTH=1000000` but when I enter this value and execute the program it returns me segmentation fault.

I tried to allocate more memory using `malloc`:

```
double **y = (double **)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(double*));
for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
  y[i] = (double *)malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
}
```

I run the the code above and after some second of calculations it still gives me "segmentation fault".
Could anyone help me?

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void *`, not a pointer to pointer.

Comment: if you know this why you are writing `(double **)malloc` ?

Comment: I copied the code from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128728/allocate-matrix-in-c]

Comment: What line is segfaulting?

Comment: [1]    4085 segmentation fault  ./pendolo_rk4_caos_G.out

Comment: allocating memory for each row is much worse for performance since it costs you millions of malloc call overhead, and the result may be not contiguous which isn't cache friendly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a dynamic allocated 2D array of the specified row-width, just do this:

```
double (*y)[4] = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(*y));
```

There is no need to malloc each row in the matrix. A single `malloc` and `free` will suffice. Only if you need *dynamic* row width (each row can vary in width independent of others) or the column count is arbitrary should a nested malloc loop be considered. Neither appears to be your case here.

Notes:

- [**Don't cast `malloc` in C programs**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1322972)
- Be sure to `free(y);` when finished with this little tryst.

Comment: I would *love* to know the reason for a down vote on this. Grow a pair and speak up.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your statically allocated array is segfaulting with a million elements is (presumably) because it's being allocated on the stack.  To have your program have a larger stack, pass appropriate switches to your compiler.

**ProTip**: You will experience less memory fragmentation and better performance if you flip your loop around, allocating

```
    (double *)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(double));
```

four times.  This will require changing the order of your indices.

> I ran the the code with this definition and after some second of calculations it still gives me "segmentatin fault"

If you're getting a segmentation fault after allocating the memory, you're writing outside of your memory bounds.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean for "appropriate switches"?

Comment: That's up to your particular compiler, and will be covered in the compiler's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// We return the pointer
int **get(int N, int M) /* Allocate the array */
{
    /* Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer) */
    int i, **table;
    table = malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        table[i] = malloc( M*sizeof(int) );
    return table;
}

void free2Darray(int** p, int N) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}

int main(void)
{
    const int LENGTH = 1000000;
    int **p;
    p = get(LENGTH, 4);
    printf("ok\n");
    free2Darray(p ,LENGTH);
    printf("exiting ok\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and it was executed normally.

I got the [code](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/) from my pseudo-site.

You should not cast what `malloc` returns. [Why?](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1047673478&id=1043284351)

Also notice, that since you need a dynamic allocation only for the number of *rows*, since you know the number of *columns*. So, you can modify the code yourself (so that you have some fun too. :) )

`I hope you didn't forget to **free** your memory.`