# How does **matrix work differently from matrix[rows][columns]?

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic

I was doing something when learning and i have encountered the next problem.
To simplify and to shorten the question i reduced the code exactly to the problem.

I want to read a matrix and just output it on my screen.
But when i run this piece of code:

```
int main(){
    int in, jn, row, col, **mat;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    mat = (int **) malloc(row * col * sizeof(int *));
    for(in = 0; in < col; in++){
        mat[in] = (int *) malloc((col + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }
    if(mat == NULL){
        printf("Error. Allocation was unsuccessful. \n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
        for(jn = 0; jn < col; jn++){
            scanf("%d", &mat[in][jn]);
        }
    }
    for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
        for(jn = 0; jn < col; jn++){
            printf("%d ", mat[in][jn]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i get segmentation fault. I debugged the program and the error appears when in = 2 and jn = 0. So i read:
1 2
3 4
and here i get the segmentation fault, when trying to read into mat[2][0]. And i do not understand why.
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjBhX.png)

And i have another version of this here:

```
int main(){
    int in, jn, row, col;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    int mat[row][col];
    for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
        for(jn = 0; jn < col; jn++){
            scanf("%d", &mat[in][jn]);
        }
    }
    for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
        for(jn = 0; jn < col; jn++){
            printf("%d ", mat[in][jn]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this one is that i can`t see the the values in watches in codeblocks. For mat[0][0](by example) instead of the first element of the matrix i see this "Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete types, try casting to a known type, or void *."

For me this is a strange behavior and i do not understand it.
Why do i get segmentation fault in the first version and why can`t i see the matrix in watches window?

Comment: The row memory allocation loop is using `col` as the loop limit which should be `row`, and you are allocating *too much* memory for the row pointers, which should be `mat = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));`

Comment: look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128728/allocate-matrix-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of memory allocation of type (*int) was off.
All you need is the number of rows.
For each row, all need is number of columns of type (int).
Here is a link to difference between array and pointer. [link](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <assert.h>

 int main(){
    int in, jn, row, col, **mat;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    mat = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    if(mat == NULL){
       printf("Error. Allocation was unsuccessful. \n");
       return 1;
     }
     for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
        mat[in] = malloc(col * sizeof(int));
        assert(mat[in]!=NULL);
     }
     for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
       for(jn = 0; jn < col; jn++){
          scanf("%d", &mat[in][jn]);
       }
     }
     for(in = 0; in < row; in++){
        for(jn = 0; jn < col; jn++){
           printf("%d ", mat[in][jn]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Nope, please look again at `mat[in] = (int *) malloc((row) * sizeof(int));`.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: @Nguaial There should be mat[in] = (int *) malloc(col * sizeof(int));

Comment: My bad.  I modified it.