Ising model simulation for 2d array with periodic boundary condition as well as plotting M vs T
As I run the code, there is no data being written to data.txt and the loop is only running once and stops between. I am not able to find any errors too. Was getting segmentation fault (core dumped).
The expected graph is supposed to be decreasing and eventually becoming flat after the critical temperature.
We are to take N, J, T as inputs and print the no. of times flipped and the final change in energy, as well as simulate this by plotting M vs T for a suitable T range.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
    
    
#define MCSTEPS 100000 // Monte Carlo steps
    
double IsingM(int **p, int N, double J, double T, int c){
    int i, j, k, iter, son;
    double M, dE, r, f;
    M = 0.0;
    iter = 0;
    
    son = (p[(i + 1) % N][j] + p[(i - 1 + N) % N][j] + p[i][(j + 1) % N] + p[i][(j - 1 + N) % N]);
    
    for ( k = 0; k < MCSTEPS; k++) {
        // Choose a random site
        i = rand() % N;
        j = rand() % N;
        
        // Calculate the energy difference
        dE = 2 * -J * p[i][j] * son;
        if(dE <=0){
            p[i][j] *= -1;
        }else{
            // Metropolis algorithm
            f = exp(-dE / T);
            r = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            if (r < f) {
                p[i][j] *= -1;
            }
        }
        iter++;
    
    }
    for(int l=0; l < N; l++){
        for(int m=0; m < N; m++){
            M += p[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Calculate magnetization
    M /= N;
    
    if (c==0){
        return M;
    }else if(c==1) {
        return iter;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if(argc != 4){
        printf("Usage : %s <N> <J> <T>\n", argv[0]);
    }
    
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    double J = atof(argv[2]);
    double T = atof(argv[3]);
    
    int **p = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    if(!p){
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
    for(int i =0; i<N; i++){
        p[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if (!p[i]) {
            printf( "Memory allocation failed for row %d\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    // Initialize t1 with random values
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            p[i][j] = rand() % 2 ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    
    FILE *fp;
    
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "w");
    double M, t;
    
    for (t = 1.0; t <= 7.0; t += 0.6) {
        M = IsingM(p, N, J, t, 0);
        fprintf(fp, "%f %f\n", t, M);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    int iter = IsingM(p, N, J, T, 1); 
    printf("%f %f %f %d", N, J, T, iter);
    
    
    // Open the data file for reading
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening data file: %s\n", fp);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Create a temporary file to store the Gnuplot commands
    FILE *gp = fopen("plot.gp", "w");
    if (gp == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating Gnuplot script.\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Write Gnuplot commands to the temporary file
    fprintf(gp, "set terminal pngcairo\n");
    fprintf(gp, "set output 'plot.png'\n");
    fprintf(gp, "plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with lines\n");
    
    // Close the Gnuplot script file
    fclose(gp);
    
    // Execute Gnuplot to create the plot
    system("gnuplot plot.gp");
    
    // Close the data file
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}


see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/2128728/8339821. from that, you can see that you should malloc sizeof(int*). you shall malloc N pointers to int, you are allocating N ints.

please edit your question to reflect the issue you have. gnuplot tag is irrelevant to the problem. name your question to something like "segfault during program execution"

Please use meaningful variable names.
